# Use gensim with existing embedding table

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, huggingface-transformers

I have generated a bunch of word embeddings using a fine-tuned transformer model from the huggingface transformers library.
Now would like do some quick evaluation, whether the results are any good. I stumbled upon gensim and saw that it had handy functions like for example `model.wv.most_similar()` and probably a few others that I could use down the line.

I was wondering if instead of loading a gensim model, I could somehow import my embedding table into it and have it use that instead, so I don't have to implement all of those functions on my own.

My embeddings are currently in a dictionary with the key, item pair being the word and its embedding vector, though I could reasonably save it in any other format.

Comment: Do you plan to continue training these vectors or just used them for downstream tasks like similarity

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I don't plan to train them further. The embedding table is "set in stone" so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Did some digging and found this article: https://www.kaggle.com/code/matsuik/convert-embedding-dictionary-to-gensim-w2v-format/notebook

With the method:

```
def save_word2vec_format(fname, vocab, vector_size, binary=True):
    """Store the input-hidden weight matrix in the same format used by the original
    C word2vec-tool, for compatibility.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fname : str
        The file path used to save the vectors in.
    vocab : dict
        The vocabulary of words.
    vector_size : int
        The number of dimensions of word vectors.
    binary : bool, optional
        If True, the data wil be saved in binary word2vec format, else it will be saved in plain text.


    """
    
    total_vec = len(vocab)
    with gensim.utils.smart_open(fname, 'wb') as fout:
        print(total_vec, vector_size)
        fout.write(gensim.utils.to_utf8("%s %s\n" % (total_vec, vector_size)))
        # store in sorted order: most frequent words at the top
        for word, row in tqdm(vocab.items()):
            if binary:
                row = row.astype(np.float32)
                fout.write(gensim.utils.to_utf8(word) + b" " + row.tostring())
            else:
                fout.write(gensim.utils.to_utf8("%s %s\n" % (word, ' '.join(repr(val) for val in row))))
```

and

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./my/path', binary=True)
```

It needed some small modification but seems to work just fine for my use case.

Comment: Yes, the `KeyedVectors` is a utility class in Gensim for loading vectors that don't need further training - but are then available for reading & common similarity/ranking operations. They're stored in a dense `numpy` array, but offer `dict`-like access by key (word) - so it's more memory efficient than a true `dict` (as every store value has less overhead) & can do optimized bulk array operations (as with a `.most_similar()` against all candidate vectors) with far less looping/calling overhead than if iterating over a normal dictionary's keys/values.